# Selecting A worksheet by name, I have the name as string

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I have a VBA code that copies a template sheet and renames it.

I have the new name saved as a public string:

"My_Tamplate" is the sheet I copy from. "PublicStringName" is the public string variable I use to rename it to.
I also use the "PublicStringName" in other places in the form, this is why I needed it as a string.

```
Sheets("My_Tamplate").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.name = PublicStringName
```

Next when I need to write the data I collected using a form, I want to write it to the newly created sheet.

Next I open a new form, collect data from the user to several variables.
Now I want to write the data into the newly created sheet (now named "PublicStringName"). If I declare WS as worksheet, it will not accept "PublicStringName" as it is a string (I think).

I do not know what sheet number it will be so I cannot call it by (sheet1) for example.

I don't know how to upload my example excel, so:

The Excel has 2 sheets named: Data (sheet2) and Project_Template (Sheet1). In sheet2 C3 I have `=MAX(B:B)`.

I have 1 form (UserForm1), it has a multi page object.

In page 1 I have a text box txtProjectName and a button cmdCreateProject.
In page 2 I have 5 text boxes, named: txtData1 to txtData5 and an Update button btnUpdate.

I tried PeterT's solution (here in the code). Attaching the problematic code here:

```
Public ProjectName

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
Set WS = ThisWorksheet.Sheets(ProjectName)
Set Addme = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)
With WS
Addme.Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.txtData1
Addme.Offset(0, 2).Value = Me.txtData2
Addme.Offset(0, 3).Value = Me.txtData3
Addme.Offset(0, 4).Value = Me.txtData4
Addme.Offset(0, 5).Value = Me.txtData5
End With
MsgBox "Contact for Project:" & " " & ProjectName & ", " & "was successfully 
added"
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCreateProject_Click()
Dim path As String
Dim mydir As String
Dim DataSh As Worksheet
Set DataSh = Sheet2
ProjectName = ""

'error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:

ProjectName = Me.txtProjectName.Value
If Me.txtProjectName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter a Project Name", vbOKOnly, "Project Name Error"
Exit Sub
End If
mydir = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & ProjectName

If Dir(mydir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir mydir
'Copy tamplate sheet to for new Project
Sheets("Project_Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = ProjectName
Else
MsgBox "Directory already exsists"
Me.txtProjectName.Value = ""
Me.txtProjectName.SetFocus
ProjectName = ""
Exit Sub
End If
Set Addme = DataSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
DataSh.Activate
DataSh.Select
With DataSh

'add the unique reference ID then all other values
Addme.Offset(0, -1) = DataSh.Range("C3").Value + 1
Addme.Value = Me.txtProjectName
End With
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Enabled = True
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(1).Visible = True
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Enabled = Fals
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Visible = Fals
Exit Sub
errHandler:
'if error occurs then show me exactly where the error occurs
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & _
" (" & Err.Description & ")in procedure PcmdClear_Click of Form ProjectDB"
End Sub
```

Now when I try to update the newly created Worksheet (named after the project) I get the error:

> Run-time error '424':
> Object required

On the line:

```
Set WS = ThisWorksheet.Sheets(ProjectName)
```

I think that Gary's Student answer is missing the step where after I create the new sheet I start collecting the data.

Comment: After you create the sheet, you can certainly use `Dim ws As Worksheet` and `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(PublicStringName)` to give you access to your new sheet.

Comment: Or `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)` after the copy.

Comment: Did not help, getting the error: Run-time error '424': 
Object required

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to use the Name:

```
Sub FreshSheet()
    Dim PublicStringNAme As String
    PublicStringNAme = "Ellan"

    Sheets("My_Tamplate").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = PublicStringNAme
    '
    '
    '
    '
    Sheets(PublicStringNAme).Range("A1") = 1
End Sub
```

If you want to make the variable "more Global" then:

```
Public PublicStringName As String

Sub FreshSheet()
    PublicStringName = "Ellan"

    Sheets("My_Tamplate").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = PublicStringName
    '
    '
    '
    '
    Sheets(PublicStringName).Range("A1") = 1
End Sub
```

See:

[Scope](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Scope.aspx)